# How to manipulate data frame to better format which is usable in ggplot?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working through some messy data where, after reading it in, it appears as the following:

```
> glimpse(il_births)
Rows: 106
Columns: 22
$ x1989       <dbl> 190247, 928, 175, 187, 445, 57, 425, 41, 207, 166, 2662, 48…
$ x1990       <dbl> 195499, 960, 192, 195, 462, 68, 449, 53, 222, 187, 2574, 47…
$ x1991       <dbl> 194066, 971, 164, 195, 464, 72, 448, 54, 179, 211, 2562, 49…
$ x1992       <dbl> 190923, 881, 189, 185, 462, 72, 414, 55, 201, 161, 2426, 46…
$ x1993       <dbl> 190709, 893, 152, 206, 497, 50, 389, 75, 202, 183, 2337, 43…
$ x1994       <dbl> 189182, 865, 158, 200, 538, 58, 429, 48, 189, 171, 2240, 41…
$ x1995       <dbl> 185801, 828, 140, 202, 566, 58, 417, 48, 173, 166, 2117, 43…
$ x1996       <dbl> 183079, 830, 147, 194, 529, 58, 417, 49, 175, 150, 2270, 41…
$ x1997       <dbl> 180649, 812, 132, 193, 531, 64, 389, 37, 163, 185, 2175, 43…
$ x1998       <dbl> 182503, 862, 140, 201, 545, 41, 417, 57, 185, 188, 2128, 41…
$ x1999       <dbl> 182027, 843, 117, 188, 595, 51, 396, 47, 193, 191, 2194, 39…
$ x2000       <dbl> 185003, 825, 132, 184, 587, 63, 434, 51, 170, 181, 2260, 40…
$ x2001       <dbl> 184022, 866, 138, 196, 629, 57, 420, 49, 147, 215, 2312, 39…
$ x2002       <dbl> 180555, 760, 129, 172, 629, 54, 434, 48, 191, 185, 2226, 39…
$ x2003       <dbl> 182393, 794, 141, 239, 668, 76, 458, 58, 154, 208, 2288, 39…
$ x2004       <dbl> 180665, 802, 126, 209, 646, 56, 396, 51, 151, 181, 2291, 42…
$ x2005       <dbl> 178872, 883, 122, 189, 744, 54, 409, 58, 160, 199, 2490, 40…
$ x2006       <dbl> 180503, 805, 112, 215, 737, 57, 392, 55, 140, 177, 2455, 41…
$ x2007       <dbl> 180530, 890, 136, 185, 736, 60, 413, 49, 163, 195, 2508, 44…
$ x2008       <dbl> 176634, 817, 120, 173, 676, 64, 409, 59, 142, 200, 2482, 40…
$ x2009       <dbl> 171077, 804, 114, 198, 622, 65, 381, 53, 123, 164, 2407, 40…
$ county_name <chr> "ILLINOIS TOTAL", "ADAMS", "ALEXANDER", "BOND", "BOONE", "B…
```

The data comes from [All Live Births In Illinois, 1989-2009](https://data.illinois.gov/dataset/77all_live_births_in_illinois_19892009). The data frame is difficult to work with, as the years are the column headers in addition to a column with all of the counties. I would prefer if the table were formatted such that there is a year column and a county column, and each row contains an observation for one year and one county. This would make it easier to work with in ggplot such that I can make some quick visualizations of the data.

I first tried transposing the data frame, but that leaves counties as rows so that does not help much.

I also tried using the `pivot_longer()` function but was not sure how to set my parameters based on my issue.

Any help or suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect a reading of `pivot_longer`'s help page would have done the trick:

> data - A data frame to pivot.
>
> cols -  Columns to pivot into longer format.
>
> names_to - A character vector specifying the new column or columns to
> create from the information stored in the column names of data
> specified by cols.
>
> values_to - A string specifying the name of the column to create from
> the data stored in cell values.

The other arguments are for more complex operations. To solve your case:

- `data` should be `il_births`
- `cols` should be all the year column names, you
  can use any tidy-select method to get them, the easier in this case
  is to say "everyone less county_name", so `-county_name`
- `names_to` is the name of the column that will have the years, by default `"name"`, but you can change it to "year" or anything else.
- `values_to` is the name of the column that will have the values, by default `"value"`, but you can change it here.

```
pivot_longer(il_births, -county_name, names_to = "year")
```

Additionally, you can remove the "x"'s from the column names, and format the year column as numeric:

```
pivot_longer(il_births, -county_name, names_to = "year",
             names_prefix = "x", names_transform = list(year = as.numeric))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full reprex of how you might read in and tidy the data. A plot is going to look very messy if you include all counties, so I have used `slice_max` to include only the five most populous counties. This line could be removed if you want to retain all the data:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- "https://data.illinois.gov/dataset/" %>%
  paste0("ac7f40df-b256-4867-9953-78c8c4a52590/",
         "resource/d7ec861b-6b7c-4260-82d8-3f05f49053f9/",
         "download/data.csv") %>%
  read.csv(check.names = FALSE) %>%
  filter(row_number() != 1) %>%
  slice_max(`_2009`, n = 5) %>% # Remove this line to keep all data 
  mutate(county_name = str_to_title(county_name)) %>%
  mutate(county_name = reorder(county_name, -`_2009`)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-county_name, names_to = "Year", values_to = "Births") %>%
  mutate(Year = as.numeric(substr(Year, 2, 5)))
```

This results in:

```r
data
#> # A tibble: 105 x 3
#>    county_name  Year Births
#>    <fct>       <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1 "Cook "      1989  94096
#>  2 "Cook "      1990  97005
#>  3 "Cook "      1991  96387
#>  4 "Cook "      1992  95140
#>  5 "Cook "      1993  94614
#>  6 "Cook "      1994  92881
#>  7 "Cook "      1995  90029
#>  8 "Cook "      1996  87747
#>  9 "Cook "      1997  85589
#> 10 "Cook "      1998  85970
#> # ... with 95 more rows
```

Which we could plot like this:

```r
ggplot(data, aes(Year, Births, color = county_name)) +
  geom_line(alpha = 0.5)  +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1", name = "County") +
  ggtitle("Live births in five most populous Illinois counties, 1989-2009") +
  labs(caption = "Source: Illinois Department of Public Health")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>